# Add rule to shoppingcart

Tags: checkout, attributes, shopping-cart-price-rules

Just like price rules, I want to apply a 'rule' but more as comment/notification that applies to certain products if they are added to the shoppingcart.

Answer (score 0):

**Hey, hope you are doing well!**

Magento 2 provides you with the possibility to create shopping cart price rules and offer your customers a discount. Let’s consider how to set up a new rule. Say, you need a rule that will give 10% off with the coupon SECRET_DISCOUNT for everyone who has this coupon or you can use it as for specific product as you want.

**Step 1**. Log in to your Admin panel and navigate to Marketing > Promotions > Cart Price Rule.

**Step 2**. Click on the Add New Rule button. On the opened page, you need to fill in 4 blocks: Rule Information, Conditions, Actions, and Label.

**Step 3**. In the Rule Information tab, set the Name, activate the rule, assign the rule to the Website, and choose the Customer Group who can use it. For our example, you need to choose the Specific Coupon in the dropdown. Limit the number of the Uses per Customer and Coupon rule. Set the Priority, if you have multiple Magento 2 cart price rules active at the same time.

[image]

**Step 4**. In the Condition tab, you can configure specific product attribute combinations, product subselection, conditions combination, or cart attributes that are needed for this rule. Or you can leave it blank to make the rule available for all products.

**Step 5**. Next is the Actions tab. There you can choose one of the available actions that should be applied to the cart:

Percent of product price discount
Fixed amount discount
Fixed amount discount for the whole cart
Buy X get Y free
Here is how it looks in our example of Magento shopping cart rule:

[image]

Set the Discount Amount and move to the last step.

**Step 6**. The last what you need to configure is the Labels tab. Enter the text for the Default Rule Label for All Store Views and Store View Specific Labels. You can create different labels for each store view.

**Step 7.** When you are ready, click on the Save button to apply the rule. Don’t forget to test the work of your shopping cart price rules on the Magento frontend.